# How to get Websockets data in multiple fragments?

Tags: java, android, websocket

I want to get data from crypto exchange via websocket in my android app(Java), I got data but only in single fragment. I have multiple fragments in which also want same data. (All the fragments are in same activity) I heard about singleton but don't know how to implement in my case.

Comment: [tag:singleton] has nothing to do with it. Your WebSocket callback will execute for every chunk of data received. It's up to you to gather them together. Too broad.

Comment: can you please suggest any source/code source/tutorial for this, I am not able go further.

Comment: Show your current code. Recommendation questions are off-topic, but there are plenty of WebSocket tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

There is some solutions:
for example:
You can get data in your webSocketClient and then send it to your Activity by callback (interface)

1. Then distribute them to all of your fragment by **invoking a method** from each fragment
2. Publish received data to all of subscribers by **RX**
3. Publish received data and get it in all of your fragments by **EventBus**
   .
   .
   .